# Java Closing Another Window with JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm currently working on a java game which opens up with a "start screen" frame. In the startscreen, I have a button called buttonLogin. Once you press buttonLogin, a login dialog launched by a LoginDialog class will pop up asking you for a username and password. In the dialog there are two buttons, login and cancel. Once you press login, my game will open, but the start screen is still visible.

My problem is that I do not know how to write code in the actionPerformed method of my LoginDialog class to close the existing StartScreen window.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If currFrame is your start screen frame. And newFrame is a frame which you want to open (game window in your case.)then set something like this....

```
currFrame.setVisible(false); // hide visibility.
ABCD newframe = new ABCD();  // load new frame named ABCD
newFrame.setVisible(true);   // make it visible.
```

Hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: I need to write code in my LoginDialog class. If I do StartScreen start = new StartScreen(); and then do start.setVisible(false); it does not work.

Comment: why you are loading a class which you just want to hide...